# Converting VB6.Format to [variable].ToString() Issues

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm currently transitioning some legacy software into `VB.NET`. I've gotten everything finished, except for some formatting.

When I try to change the following to [variable].ToString():

This: `VB6.Format(Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1), "0") & "   "`

To This: `Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1).ToString("0") & "   "`

I receive a runtime error stating: `Error when converting 'String' to 'IFormatProvider'.`

Both variables `inputrec3` and `I` are declared as objects. I am unsure of what the issue is. I've already tried changing their declarations to an `Int`, and placing the `Mid` method into a variable and trying to format it that way, to no avail.

I am unsure of what else I should try to get this last piece to work. I understand I can keep it as `VB6.Format` but I'd prefer to use something more updated for the long-run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `String.ToString()` doesn't make sense. Are you trying to format a number as having one digit? It looks like you only need `Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1) & "   "` since you already return one character / digit from `Mid`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is the data at inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I)?

Comment: @djv, yes I am trying to format a number to one digit.

Comment: Let me try that now, @djv. I will get right back with you.

Comment: If you want to format a number then you need a number.  A `String` that contains digit characters is not a number.

Comment: `I've already tried changing their declarations to an Int` @jmcilhinney

Comment: What does the string `inputrec3` look like? Specifically at position `129 + (21 * I)`

Comment: @rad_ Could `inputrec3` ever be shorter than `129 + (21 * I) + 1` characters long?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes it could. Just not formatting fixed the issue since `Mid` does only return a single digit. I appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: @rad_ You might need to add a `.PadLeft(1, "0"c)` to account for the cases where an empty string is returned by the `Mid` function (which might have been the function of the `Format(.... "0")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need

```
Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1) & " "
```

because `Mid` is already returning a one character string based on the arguments. If it's a number already then you don't need to format it at all.

However, see [VB6 Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) which suggests that when passed a one character string, `Format(string, "0")` will return a one character string with

- If `string` is numeric, will return the single digit number
- If `string` is non-numeric, will return a "0"

So **if you *could* have a non-number at position** `129 + (21 * I)`, then your VB6 would return a zero, and now you'd be getting an empty string. You may want to handle this.

```vb
Dim input = 0
Integer.TryParse(Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1), input)
Dim result = $"{input}   "
```

Comment: Thank you for further clarifying! I will definitely handle it like you described. It seems that will be the best bet so the data isn't misinformed. I'm doing a data run right now with that, I will let you know the results.

Comment: Data run is complete. The format is structured like it should be. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `Mid` function returns a string. `string.ToString` does not have an overload that takes a format string. The "legacy" code seems to be implicitly converting the string returned from `Mid` into a number when calling the `Format` function. In VB.NET you may need to do that explicitly:

```
CInt(Mid(inputrec3, 129 + (21 * I), 1)).ToString("0")
```

Or see if `Mid` gives you the string you want instead of converting it from a string to an integer and back.

Comment: That is exactly what happened when the conversion happened. Thank you for the input. This would have worked as well, but since `Mid` already returns one digit per my arguments, I just completely removed formatting all together. Completely overlooked this.